# Query in Editing CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have column names in a list and I want to assign value 1 to these column names and assign value 0 to rest of the columns.
Ex.

```
perms_name = ['name','place','thing']
```

Initially CSV looks like:

```
name,age,place,thing,phone_no
```

I want to make the csv look like:

```
name,age,place,thing,phone_no
1,0,1,1,0
```

I can do this simply by this

```
with open('eggs.csv','a') as csvfile:
    fieldname = ["name","age","place","thing","phone_no"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()

    writer.writerow(
        {'name': 1,'age':0,'place':1,'thing':1,'phone_no':0}
    )
```

but is their any faster way, In this case their are only 5 columns what if their are 100 columns and I want to assign 1 only to the columns mentions in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack dictionaries in-line in Python 3 via the `**` operator. Combining with `dict.fromkeys`, there's no need to write out keys and values explicitly for each field:

```
perms_name = ['name','place','thing']
fieldname = ['name', 'age', 'place', 'thing', 'phone_no']

d = {**dict.fromkeys(fieldname, 0), **dict.fromkeys(perms_name, 1)}

{'age': 0, 'name': 1, 'phone_no': 0, 'place': 1, 'thing': 1}
```

Define your dictionary once and then use:

```
writer.writerow(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

alternately to jpp's answer, you can use a slightly confusing list comprehension to build the dictionary.

```
perms_name = ['name','place','thing']
fieldname = ['name', 'age', 'place', 'thing', 'phone_no']
d = {field : (1 if field in perms_name else 0) for field in fieldname}
# {'name': 1, 'age': 0, 'place': 1, 'thing': 1, 'phone_no': 0}
```

it also might be worthwhile if there are an arbitrary number of columns to read them from the csv rather than hard-coding them into your script.

Comment: It worked, thankyou very much. Can you help me with a new query, How I will build my dictionary if in the same question as above I want to assign string value to the name field and the rest fields are the same as mentioned above.

Comment: probably the simplest is to build it as above and then re-assign `d['name'] = 'some string value'` after the dictionary comprehension (but before writing it obviously).